# Where can I find a comprehensive collection of all American Founding Fathers' writings?

Tags: united-states, colonial-america, american-revolution, book, founding-fathers

I was taught in school that the Founding Fathers of America were very prolific and that they produced many documents during their time, including books, pamphlets, magazines, letters, diaries, etc. For a few years, I've been interested in finding some sort of comprehensive collection of their writings which essentially places all of their writings under one "roof," sorted by writer and date, but I cannot seem to find any such book if it exists.

I've found many separate works written by individual Founding Fathers, but what I'm looking for is more like the [*Ante-Nicene Fathers*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ante-Nicene_Fathers_(book)) collection, which collects almost all of the early Christian writings into a single, compact multi-volume series. I imagined that something like this must exist for the American Founding Fathers as well, but I can't seem to find such a work if it does exist.

Additionally, I would like to know if there are similar collections of their private / personal documents such as letters, diaries, manuscripts, etc. I'm aware of a few websites (e.g., https://founders.archives.gov) which seems to collect much of their correspondence and other writings, and while that particular website is massive, it doesn't contain everything from [all of the men](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Founding_Fathers_of_the_United_States) considered "Founding Fathers." I would like to have compilations which collect both:

- all of their published writings
- all of their private / personal writings, like letters, diaries, manuscripts, etc.

I recognize that the latter type may only be available in online resources, but if major Founding Fathers' correspondences have been published in some sort of work(s), I would like to know about that. I'm mainly interested in works from the 18th-19th centuries (i.e., 1700s-1800s). I want to get as close to primary-source materials as possible. However, if there are 20th- or even 21st-century publications which have [critical-text editions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Textual_criticism) or other heretofore unpublished writings, I would be interested in those as well. If no such comprehensive collection has been published like the *Ante-Nicene Fathers*, I would like a large bibliography or list of reliable websites where I can access the Founding Fathers' primary-source writings for myself.

Comment: The proper word for that wouldn't be "collection" but rather "library". There's a *lot*

Comment: @T.E.D.: That suggests to me a "unit of (published) work": the **Euler**, being the quantity of published work of Leonhard Euler. As the Swiss Academy has been republishing Euler's collected works since shortly before the First World War, with only two brief interludes during the World Wars, and is not quite yet done., one sees that the **Euler** is quite substantial. I wonder how the Federalist and Anti-Federalist Papers, for example, compare; or for that matter, the entire written (political) output of the Founding Fathers.

Comment: @PieterGeerkens - Unfortunately, the [Euler Number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/E_(mathematical_constant)) is already A Thing (aka: *e*). However, I was thinking more in terms of The Library of Congress, which I believe was chartered in part for this purpose. Since you mention it, I have in fact seen "Libraries of Congress" [being used as a measure for information](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_unusual_units_of_measurement#Data_volume) before.

Comment: You may also find this website useful in trying to locate online repositories of their works: https://guides.loc.gov/american-founders-papers/introduction

Comment: That Founding Fathers Wiki is incredibly subjective with whom they include on the page. Basically, anyone with even a minor role in early American history is listed, such as being a victim of the Boston Massacre. If you are looking for ALL of the papers of ALL of the people on that Wikipedia I am certain you will not find it. The papers of all these individuals will be scattered across dozens of institutions. And, I am certain that not all of their documents survive to this day, and I am sure that many are in private collections. Maybe you could define who the Founding Fathers were?

Comment: @JimmyG. Hmmm, well I guess you're right in that potentially hundreds of individuals could be considered "Founding Fathers." I guess I'd be satisfied with the ones listed on https://founders.archives.gov/ as a starting-point, namely: George Washington, Benjamin Franklin, John Adams, Thomas Jefferson, Alexander Hamilton, John Jay, and James Madison.

Comment: On that website, there are links to the papers of each of those men. The collections are vast, and none of them are entirely online. Nearly 300k pages for the Adams papers, 30k for Franklin, 135k for Washington, etc. I am reasonably sure that website is the most complete collection of online primary sources regarding the Founding Fathers. I have been through several pages of several Google searches, and I find nothing that comes close. Those Ante-Nicene books, (10 vol. set >7k p) would be dwarfed by ONE of the founding fathers writings, let alone all of them.

Comment: [The papers of Thomas Jefferson](https://press.princeton.edu/collected-works/collected-thomas-jefferson) alone comprise 47 volumes. So, I am pretty confident the answer to your question is no. There is no single online repository of ALL of the Founding Fathers documents. Not all of their TREMENDOUS volumes of papers have been digitized, though you can buy the complete sets of their papers (minus John Jay) via links on that website.